# Change characteristics of USB host mode programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, serial-communication, usbserial

I'm working in **serial communication** project using **USB** in host mode device won't charge, found some unsafe solutions for this is like **Type-c USB cord** or  **OTG-Y connector**.

Another solution is rooting mobile and setting

```
 rp.usb_host = 0
```

what would happen if we change **rp.usb_host=0** will the device act as the host and will charge the device or the device wont act as the host at all? will serial communication get interrupts? 
is there any better solution for this using coding?